# PonyORM - How to convert python generator expression to SQL without defining tables

Tags: ponyorm

Usually we need to define tables firstly, then PonyOrm can translate python generator expressions to AST and further into SQL statements to query tables. Is it possible to convert a python expression string into SQL without defining the table schema firstly? I don't need to connect to the database in my case, and just want to utilize python generator expression to simply the coding of SQL query statements, and convert the SQL to different data source APIs using other tools (the data sources are not real database). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want not to define entities - no, Pony needs to know the database structure.

If you just want to work without database connection, you can specify it like `Database('sqlite', ':memory:')`